# Keycloak upgrade to 16.1.0 fails

Tags: migration, keycloak

I am trying to migrate keycloak from 11 to 16.1.0 and fails with, the following error ... I have removed all smallrye entries in standalone.xml, how can I see a more detailed error message?

the migration is run via

```
bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=bin/migrate-standalone.cli

*** WARNING ***

** If the following embed-server command fails, manual intervention is needed.
** In such case, remove any <extension> and <subsystem> declarations referring
** to the removed smallrye modules from the standalone.xml file and rerun this script.
** For details, see Migration Changes section in the Upgrading guide.
** We apologize for this inconvenience.

Cannot start embedded server: WFLYEMB0021: Cannot start embedded process: JBTHR00005: Operation failed: WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem, upgrading from 15.0.2 to 16.1, standalone mode + external MySQL database.

#EDIT

I've found this... - https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/upgrading/#migrating-to-16-0-0

> Due to the amount of changes we are not able to provide migration scripts as we have done in the past.

> We recommend that rather than copying configuration files from previous versions of Keycloak that you start with the default configuration files provided in Keycloak 16 and apply the relevant changes.

Comment: After the changes it no longer acts as a https enabled server behind a nginx proxy and the documentation send you to no specific places